# How to auto query until script is closed/killed using python / pyodbc?

Tags: python, refresh, reload

I have a script reading a query into a PYSIDE UI how can I have it auto refresh every 5 minutes until script is closed? aside from programming a refresh button?

I am using python and PySide. Can anyone direct me to an article or library that could possibly do what I need it to do?

Comment: Try `threading.Timer`. Basically you invoke the `Timer` in the end of your query function, and recursively call the query function itself inside `Timer`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer from @Ian helped me.

I am using `from threading import Timer, Thread`

it also helped me build a countdown LCD.

My sql query lives in the following function at the end I called the timer function:

```
def on_push_button_clicked(self):
    Sql= 'Select * From X'...

    self.querytimer()

def querytimer():
    Timer(116.0, self.on_push_button_clicked).start()
```